# How to store next/return URL in Django FormView

Tags: django

I have a Django FormView that has two entry points from different edit buttons on different URLs. Once the user is done editing, I would like to return then to the URL they were originally on.

To do this, I need to know the URL the user originally came from.

So far, I have done the following: include a `next` parameter in the call to the `FormView`, then add that `next` parameter to the form `action` so that when the form is posted I can retrieve it e.g.

```
<form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/2/item/update?next=read_view">
...
</form>
```

However, on the form post I cannot seem to get hold of the `action` to get the `next` parameter.

Is there a standard way to handle this in Django? My approach feels a bit clunky.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the form is submitted, you can use the redirect method

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

if request.method == 'POST':
   form = form_input(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return redirect(name_of_the_url_page_you_want_redirect_to)
```

Comment: thanks, that'll be useful once I've working out how to pass the url around!